# How can I make an acceleration mechanic using WinForms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, picturebox

I'm trying to write a movement mechanic like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6jtX.png) but how can I? If we hold to `Space` key, character in the game will move like in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uwzI.gif). If we take our hand from the key, the character will fall against to gravity. I did a research for about two hours but this site is the last solution way for me.

There is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace c_sharp_form_test_2 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            timer.Interval = 5;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(FormUpdate);
            timer.Start();
        }

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        Bitmap bitmap;
        Point center = new Point(100, 100);
        int radius = 40;
        int FigureSize = 10;

        Point end;
        float angle = -90;
        float angVel = 0;
        float angAcc = 0;

        bool isPressing = false;

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space) {
                isPressing = true;
                angle += 10;
            }
        }
        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            angVel = 0;
            angAcc = 0;
            isPressing = false;
        }

        private void FormUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            end.X = (int)(radius * Math.Sin(angle / 57.2957795f)) +             center.X;// from degrees to radians
            end.Y = (int)(radius * Math.Cos(angle / 57.2957795f)) +     center.Y;// from degrees to radians

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        Pen bp = new Pen(Color.Black);
        SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

        g.Clear(Color.White);
        g.FillEllipse(b, end.X - FigureSize / 2, end.Y - FigureSize / 2, FigureSize, FigureSize);
        g.DrawLine(bp, center.X, center.Y, end.X, end.Y);
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;

        if (!isPressing) {
            angle += angVel;
            angVel += angAcc;
            angAcc = -0.15f * (float)Math.Sin(angle / 57.2957795f);
            angVel *= 0.985f;//dampening
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks from now!

Answer (score 0):

i can't add a comment cause of reputation,
so

you can look these articles and code sample to find your way to the light;

```
private void DrawIt()
        {
            System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(
                50, 100, 150, 150);
            graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rectangle);
            graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, rectangle);
        }
```

[codeProjectLink](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/70200/Draw-a-pie-chart-in-C-net-win-forms)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-draw-a-filled-ellipse-on-a-windows-form?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 0):

In the Form you need to double click the KeyUp and KeyDown events and also create a picturebox from the toolbox. The Timer is working like an update to do something every second. I didn't implement figure rotation but you can do that by using Sin and Cosine around the endpoint, and every angle is divided by 57... because all the trig calculations are done in radians, and degrees just feel more natural.

If you are planning to build a reasonably big game, then you're probably should use a game engine, because the input, physics and drawing systems are much more simple for you to work with in those programs.

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TrynaHelppl
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            timer.Interval = 5;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(FormUpdate);
            timer.Start();
        }

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        Bitmap bitmap;
        Point center = new Point(100, 100);
        int radius = 40;
        int FigureSize = 10;

        Point end;
        float angle = -90;
        float angVel = 0;
        float angAcc = 0;

        bool isPressing = false;

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
                isPressing = true;
                angle += 10;
            }
        }
        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            angVel = 0;
            angAcc = 0;
            isPressing = false;
        }

        private void FormUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            end.X = (int)(radius * Math.Sin(angle / 57.2957795f)) + center.X;// from degrees to radians
            end.Y = (int)(radius * Math.Cos(angle / 57.2957795f)) + center.Y;// from degrees to radians

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            Pen bp = new Pen(Color.Black);
            SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

            g.Clear(Color.White);
            g.FillEllipse(b, end.X - FigureSize / 2, end.Y - FigureSize / 2, FigureSize, FigureSize);
            //g.DrawLine(bp, center.X, center.Y, end.X, end.Y);
            pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;

            if (!isPressing)
            {
                angle += angVel;
                angVel += angAcc;
                angAcc = -0.15f * (float)Math.Sin(angle / 57.2957795f);
                angVel *= 0.985f;//dampening
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dude sorry but I don't know how to use trigonometric calculations :/ Can you help me again?

Comment: Sin function takes in angle in radians and gives the vertical length from 0 to a line with a length of 1 raised at that angle and cos gives the horizontal one, so you need to rotate your points of a figure arount the Point named end. Did the original example work?

Comment: The code didn't work. nothing happend. And KeyPreview setted to True.

Comment: No. I saw just the form and a non-imaged picture box. Want to see the code?

Comment: Just click view code on the form in solution explorer

Comment: Look man, you're misusing stack overflow. For your project you can find a radar code in c# and a video about pendulums by coding train, you should be able to merge them together if you know what you're doing and not just blindly following the tutorials. Stackoverflow should be a forum about questions that you can't find answer's about anywhere else, bugs that no one said how to fix, not to solve your homework. Here are the 2 videos I talked about, you'll get code similar to mine 
Radar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WhQATRycTU 
Pendulum: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iaEqGOh5WM&t=929s